# SC command stop if not already stopped

Tags: cmd

Im building a process that involves running the SC command to stop a service before deleting some files.  However, this process fails if the service is already stopped because this command returns an error.
Is there a way to skip this error or only stop if not already stopped.  I can do this with powershell, but just wondering if there is an option with a command line switch of some sort?

Comment: `"%__AppDir__%sc.exe" Query SERVICE_NAME | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /RC:"STATE *: 4" 1> NUL && "%__AppDir__%sc.exe" Stop SERVICE_NAME` Or you could query for inactive services, and do the opposite, `"%__AppDir__%sc.exe" Query state= inactive | "%__AppDir__%find.exe" /I "SERVICE_NAME" 1> NUL || "%__AppDir__%sc.exe" Stop SERVICE_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the needful, it checks to see that the results of SCQuery are "4  Running" before running the stop command.

Note I have the script check to output the status again after a 3 second pause so you can use that to wait for a status if you need to with a little changing.

```
@(
  SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_ServiceName=Your SVC"
  SET "_Action=Stop"
  SET "_Pause=ping 5.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000 >NUL"
)

CALL :Main

(
  ENDLOCAL
  EXIT /B
)

:Main
  (
    SC  query "%_ServiceName%" | FIND /I "STATE              : 4  RUNNING"
  ) && (
    SC  %_Action% "%_ServiceName%"
  )
  ECHO.Pausing a few seconds...
    %_Pause%
  SC  query "%_ServiceName%" | FIND /I "STATE"
  %_Pause%
GOTO :EOF
```